# Assign a value to a sub group if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to create column and assign a number to each team that won and lost in a given 'Rally' (0 for a Loss, 1 for a Win). The last row of each rally will display who won in the 'Points' column.

The image shows how the data is formatted and the desired result is in the 'Outcome' column:
[image: The image shows how the data is formatted and the desired result is in the 'Outcome' column]

My current code is;

```py
def winLoss(x):
    if 'A' in x['Points']:
        if x.TeamAB == 'A':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    elif 'B' in x['Points']:
        if x.TeamAB == 'B':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

df['Outcome'] = df.groupby('Rally').apply(winLoss).any()
```

Comment: Why the first row of `Rally == 2` displays A with outcome 1?

Comment: Team A won the point in Rally #2 so i want to add 1 to all rows in group where TeamAB == 'A'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the winners for each rally by grouping and taking the last row of `Points` for each group, then use multiindex to loc filter an assign the `Outcome`:

```
winners = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
    df.groupby(['Rally'])['Points']
    .last().str.slice(-1).reset_index()
)

df.set_index(['Rally', 'TeamAB'], inplace=True)
df['Outcome'] = 0
df.loc[df.index.isin(winners), 'Outcome'] = 1
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```